# MongoDB: cursor.count() when using collation is inaccurate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using collation in Mongo (v3.4 using the native node driver) to do a case-insensitive search for an API endpoint.  As part of the response, I send metadata about the query back to the consumer which includes the count the matching documents.  Everything was working fine until I introduced the collation...  Now, it seems, the cursor.count() method does not include the documents that were matched by the collation operation.

Consider that we are searching a collection called 'docs' filtered for the username.  We have 15 documents with a username value of 'foo', and 30 documents with a username value of 'Foo'.  The code looks like this:

```
// 'query' is the query params submitted to the API endpoint and then parsed for use
const cursor = db.collection('docs').find(query,
  { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } });

cursor.count()
  .then((count) => {
    console.log(count);
  })
  .then(//send the response
```

When the 'query' is 'foo', the count that is logged is: 15 (the number of documents whose 'username' value is exactly 'foo'.  When the 'query is 'Foo', however, the count that is logged is 30, which is the exact number of documents whose 'username' value is exactly 'Foo'.  In BOTH cases, however, 45 documents are sent as the response (which is correct, given the collation).

What is causing the disparity here?  Is there a way for cursor.count() to reflect the total number of results?

Comment: This is curious behaviour indeed. I have created https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1369 to see if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Kevin - thank you for looking into this and submitting a ticket.  Great to see the support that Mongo provides for its products!